# Charger keeps disconnecting - Windows issue?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, charger, hp-elitebook

My Hp laptop charger keeps disconnecting and reconnecting. After 20 secs, it disconnects, and 5 secs later, it reconnects.
I've noticed this behavior only when laptop is turned on.
Here's what I tried:

- Uninstalled battery drivers from Device Manager *(worked for about an hour but issue is happening again now)*
- Running in Safe Mode *(It worked fine there)*
- Restoring default bios and power settings

I googled and tried other solutions as well. Charger works fine when laptop is turned off, but so soon as windows starts, the whole thing starts happening.

My specs:

*Hp Elitebook 8460*
*Intel Core i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz*
*4 GB ram*
*Windows 10 (64 bit)*

**EDIT**:

- I also **resetted** the Windows but no benefit

<strike>**EDIT 2:**</strike>

- This only happens when the battery is like less than almost 50% (not exact) or a close value

Comment: Look in your HP Battery App (or the HP App that contains the Battery App).  There may be a threshold setting that says "Charge to here (not 100%) and allow to drop to here (lower value)"  See if you have this kind of setting (I do on my Lenovo laptops) and then see if it has been set correctly.

Comment: Try booting a Linux Live USB disk.  See if it happens there.  It is often helpful for troubleshooting "is this windows or the hardware itself?" problems.

Comment: *"is this windows or the hardware itself?"* I have no idea either. I am confused. As I said, when the laptop is turned off, it works fine. @SeñorCMasMas

Comment: It could be the charger is failing and unable to provide the necessary power drain. When the computer is off it isn't pulling as much energy and so the issue doesn't continue. This is just a guess though.

Comment: If this works fine in Safe Mode, then perhaps some startup app is responsible. To turn startups off temporarily use [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to turn them off in bunches, then reboot. Easy to undo afterward.

Comment: How do you know it is disconnecting and connecting when turned on?  Are you checking this by looking at the taskbar / tray icon?  If so, how do you know it is not also doing it when turned off?  My laptop has a power light next to the plughole which indicates when it's receiving power through the lead, whether or not the laptop is turned on.  Does yours have anything similar?  What is it's behaviour?

Comment: @5Diraptor My laptop has power led next to plug hole, yea. When the laptop is turned off, the light stays on, but when the laptop is running, the light blinks as the charger keeps disconnecting

Comment: OK, good to know.  How old is your PC?  Is it possible you could have got your charger mixed up with another one?  Curious that uninstalling drivers worked for a short while.  It feels as if they may have been reinstalled automatically an hour later and the problem started occuring again?  Can you check to see if the drivers are installed again?  If so, try uninstalling them, let me know the results.

Comment: Also, pull the battery and do a physical check on it - any bulges or cracks?  It might have connection pins on the laptop or battery - are any of these bent or broken?

Answer (score 1):

I would run the [HP Support Assistant](https://support.hp.com/us-en/topic/diagnostics?category=computing&issue=battery-adapter-issues) which includes the Battery Check diagnostic to test that will test your battery and provide solutions to issues that may affect your battery or power adapter.

In some cases, I've seen a 65W power adapter will keep a laptop powered on but not charge it vs a 90W power adapter.

Although it appears to work in Safe Mode it is more likely a hardware issue. Especially if you have reinstalled Windows and have no software or have made any changes regarding how the computer manages hardware.

Answer (score 1):

First I would make sure it's not a mechanical issue: push the connector to each side for several seconds, rotate it half a revolution, and pull the cable to each side while holding the connector in place. Do this test while the laptop is sleeping or powered off, when the charger is supposed to always work. Keep a close look to the charge indicator: if it changes color while you do this, you likely have a broken wire or an oxidized connector. Another test you could do is running the laptop with the battery removed: if there's a mechanical problem with the power connector, the laptop will instantly switch off.

If the mechanical issue is out of the question, you either have a defective PSU, an undersized PSU (impossible if it's the original which came with the laptop), or a defective battery. The most conclusive test would be to obtain a temporary replacement (from a friend or a shop which accepts free returns), replace the suspected part and see if the issue goes away.